# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <recently read> \endtemplate give this error help please

Tags: tables, alignment

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Table 6: Numerical comparison when effect of parameter $\Omega$ on $TMGS$ and $MGS$} \\
\hline
Example & $m$ & $\Omega$ & $TMGS$ & $MGS$ [51] \\
& $IT$ & $CPT$ & $RES$ \\
\hline
5.1 & $500^2$ & $0.8I$ & 15 & $0.9254$ & $3.4521e^{-6}$ & 29 & $3.3189$ & $4.8204e^{-6}$ \\
 & & $I$ & 12 & $0.6894$ & $7.4843e^{-6}$ & 23 & $2.5706$ & $9.3893e^{-6}$ \\
 & & $1.2I$ & 8 & $0.6538$ & $5.3515e^{-6}$ & 20 & $2.3163$ & $6.9406e^{-6}$ \\
5.2 & $500^2$ & $0.8I$ & 14 & $0.871$ & $3.9402e^{-6}$ & 26 & $3.0118$ & $6.6218e^{-6}$ \\
 & & $I$ & 12 & $0.8008$ & $2.4597e^{-6}$ & 21 & $2.3374$ & $4.9377e^{-6}$ \\
 & & $1.2I$ & 7 & $0.6521$ & $4.8521e^{-6}$ & 17 & $1.9623$ & $7.5469e^{-6}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: You've defined the `tabular` environment to have 7 columns, yet your code tries to typeset 9 columns in most rows. What is the table supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating seven columns, but there are nine in the body of the table, so you would be served with

```
|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|
```

in the argument to `tabular`.

On the other hand there's much room for improvement. First, the caption should not be in the body of the table and not manually numbered. With the `caption` package you can easily modify the appearance of your captions.

Numeric tables will always benefit from `siunitx`, so I'd use it as shown below. Also, vertical rules are good for spreadsheets, not for printed tables, notwithstanding what you see from word processor printouts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Numerical comparison when effect of parameter $\Omega$ on TMGS and MGS}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  c
  c
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4e-1]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4e-1]
}
\toprule
Example & $m$ & $\Omega$ & {TMGS} & {MGS} & {[51]} & {IT} & {CPT} & {RES} \\
\midrule
5.1 & $500^2$ & $0.8I$ & 15 & 0.9254 & 3.4521e-6 & 29 & 3.3189 & 4.8204e-6 \\
    &         & $I$    & 12 & 0.6894 & 7.4843e-6 & 23 & 2.5706 & 9.3893e-6 \\
    &         & $1.2I$ &  8 & 0.6538 & 5.3515e-6 & 20 & 2.3163 & 6.9406e-6 \\
\addlinespace
5.2 & $500^2$ & 0.8I   & 14 & 0.871  & 3.9402e-6 & 26 & 3.0118 & 6.6218e-6 \\
    &         & $I$    & 12 & 0.8008 & 2.4597e-6 & 21 & 2.3374 & 4.9377e-6 \\
    &         & $1.2I$ &  7 & 0.6521 & 4.8521e-6 & 17 & 1.9623 & 7.5469e-6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `tabular*` we can fill the full textwidth and leave to TeX the intercolumn spaces. If you see that the table becomes too cramped, you can add `\small` next to `\centering` and retry. Maybe `\footnotesize` if the table is pretty big.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error message always means that there is some mismatch between the number of "allocated" columns (in `{...}` directly after `\begin{tabular}`) and the number of columns that you try to use in the body, separated by `&`.

I assume that the table should look like this:
[image]

In that case you need to change the number of columns in the following way:

```
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Table 6: Numerical comparison when effect of parameter $\Omega$ on $TMGS$ and $MGS$} \\
            \hline
            Example & $m$ & $\Omega$ & $TMGS$ & $MGS$ & [51]            & $IT$ & $CPT$ & $RES$ \\
            \hline
...
```

Note, that there is also something strange in the line strating with `Example & ...`. I am not sure if this is how you wanted it, thgouh.